# Getting DVD chapter timings

Tags: .net, directshow.net, managed-directx

I'm working on small DVD player (using DirectShow.Net), and require start time of a chapter with respect to it's title.

I'm looking for a way to find out the start time of a chapter within a title. Or may be the duration of each chapter within a title, which will allow me to calculate the start of any chapter by adding up the duration of chapters before it.

Any ideas?

I found [.NET DVD Library](http://dvdlibnet.codeplex.com/), any one found it useful?